# Dynamic routes in express, "Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined" error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to dynamically create routes in nodejs using express by getting the pages from mongodb database.

My code in `routes.js` is something like:

```js
module.exports = function(app, passport) {
    Page.find(function(err,leroutedata){
        leroutedata.forEach(function(page) {
            var path = page.path;
            app.get(path,function(req, res){
                res.render('layout.ejs', { data : page });
            });
        });
     });
};
```

But I get this error:

```
(...)/node_modules/path-to-regexp/index.js:34
    .concat(strict ? '' : '/?')
    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined
```

Any ideea what can cause it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `page.path` may not a string or Regex

Comment: I changed `var path = String(page.path);` and now my code works... Thanks!